# Replace a string numpy array with a number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
z = array(['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa','Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-versicolor','Iris-virginica', 'Iris-virginica', 'Iris-virginica'])
```

I want to replace

```
Iris-setosa -0
Iris-versicolor - 1
Iris-virginica - 2
```

to apply logistic regression.

Final output should be like

```
z = [ 0, 0 ,.. 1,1,.. 2,2,..]
```

Is there a simple way to do this operation instead of iterating through the array and use replace command?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but maybe another idea: `pd.Series(z, dtype="category")`, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

Comment: Your example is ambiguous. Are the strings supposed to be numbered in order of appearance or substituted with a given value?

Comment: The fact that you want to subsequently apply logistic regression does not make this a `machine-learning` question; please do not spam the tag (removed)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
a = pd.factorize(z)[0].tolist()
print (a)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Or [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
a = np.unique(z, return_inverse=True)[1].tolist()
print (a)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: @Sanjay - Glad can help!

Answer (score 11):

you can use a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'Iris-setosa': 0, 'Iris-versicolor': 1, 'Iris-virginica': 2}
```

then use list comprehension:

```
z = [my_dict[zi] for zi in z]
```

Comment: That really helped. I need to convert it from numpy array to list before doing the operation.

Comment: this syntactic sugar is useful right now for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to count the number of occurrence as you are trying to do logistic regression?

If yes, you can use the following as well.

```
import collections
z = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa','Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-versicolor','Iris-virginica', 'Iris-virginica', 'Iris-virginica']
print (collections.Counter(z))
```

It will print as below:

```
Counter({'Iris-setosa': 4, 'Iris-versicolor': 3, 'Iris-virginica': 3})
```

If you want to print in another way, you can do the following:

```
import collections
z = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa','Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-versicolor','Iris-virginica', 'Iris-virginica', 'Iris-virginica']
for item in collections.Counter(z):
    print(str(item)+ ' ' + str(collections.Counter(z)[item]))
```

The output will be

```
Iris-setosa 4
Iris-versicolor 3
Iris-virginica 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[list(set(z)).index(val) for val in z]
```

simply put, cast a set out of z to get only unique values, then cast a list out of that set for indexing, then finally use a list comprehension to get the final list.  If you have a very large list of strings, I would suggest setting list(set(z)) to a variable outside of the list comprehension

Comment: I got the output as `[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]` but isn't Iris-setosa be set to 0

Comment: How about this `[list(np.unique(z)).index(val) for val in z]`